# Aptana places Dojo require array and function on one line. Is there a way to spread these over multiple lines?

Tags: eclipse, dojo, aptana

As an extreme example:

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/dnd/Manager", "js/desktop/desktopAvatar", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojo/has", "dijit/layout/TabController", "js/desktop/desktopCommons", "dijit/layout/StackController", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/dnd/common", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/json", "dojo/dom-form", "js/desktop/desktopSource", "dijit/popup", "js/desktop/desktopBorderContainer", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dojox/layout/ContentPane"], function(lang, Manager, desktopAvatar, Menu, MenuItem, has, TabController, desktopCommons, StackController, domConstruct, on, query, domAttr, domClass, dndCommons, xhr, JSON, domForm, desktopSource, popup, DesktopBorderContainer, ready, dom, registry, parser) {
```

Default Javascript editor in Eclipse applies this formatting:

```
require(
        [ "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/dnd/Manager", "js/desktop/desktopAvatar",
                "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojo/has",
                "dijit/layout/TabController", "js/desktop/desktopCommons",
                "dijit/layout/StackController", "dojo/dom-construct",
                "dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-class",
                "dojo/dnd/common", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/json",
                "dojo/dom-form", "js/desktop/desktopSource", "dijit/popup",
                "js/desktop/desktopBorderContainer", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom",
                "dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
                "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/TooltipDialog",
                "dojox/layout/ContentPane" ],
        function(lang, Manager, desktopAvatar, Menu, MenuItem, has,
                TabController, desktopCommons, StackController, domConstruct,
                on, query, domAttr, domClass, dndCommons, xhr, JSON, domForm,
                desktopSource, popup, DesktopBorderContainer, ready, dom,
                registry, parser) {
```

For all other formatting, Aptana works better, but that very long first line makes it harder to add new required items etc.

Is there a way to use Aptana Javascript formatting, but where long arrays and function inputs are split over lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we're using Aptana too & just set up the require by ourself and make a break after each entry.

Then it looks like this :

```
require([
                    "dojo/_base/array",
                    "dojo/_base/Color",
                    "dojo/_base/window",
                    "dojo/dom",
                    "dojo/dom-construct",
                    "dojo/dom-style",
                    "dojo/json",
                    "dojo/on",
                    "dijit/registry",
                    "dojox/layout/FloatingPane"],
                     function(
                        array,
                        color,
                        win,
                        dom,
                        domConstruct,
                        domStyle,
                        JSON,
                        on,
                        registry,
                        FloatingPane){
```

It's the easiest way to make it more clearly.